# Speed up VBA with 138k rows and ~330 sheet creation

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a VBA script that does the following and I am trying to see if I can have it perform faster than 44 seconds:

1. start with ~138k rows of data on sheets("Data")
2. concatenate each cell in the row into a temp string variable

   - temp string will look some like this if my row are columns A:D, "I am cellAI am cell BI am cell CI am cell D"
3. sort the column holding all temp strings, so I can see all duplicates
4. filter to first temp string value to get the count of each occurrence
5. copy count into a sheets("reporting") and hyperlink the count number
6. create a new sheet that is opened from the hyperlink

   - in the end, after all count of duplicate strings are accounted for, I am creating 345 sheets
7. copy the filtered results into the newly created sheet
8. hide the sheet
9. repeat steps 4 through 8

My question is, based on the amount of work being done, is 38 - 44 seconds reasonable or can it be in any way faster (less than 30 seconds)

Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub runReportV2()

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '-V1 code
    ' - allow user to create grouping of fields
    ' - create temp strings of each row
    ' - compare all temp strings with each other
    ' - get count of each duplicate string occurrence and paste count to 'Report Summary' sheet
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '-V2 code
    ' - adding hyperlinks to aggregation count on Report Summary sheet
    ' - linking hyperlinks to a new sheet with filtered row data from data sheet
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'These will help speed things up
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Dim x As Double ' used for the For Loop when creating temp strings
    Dim y As Double ' used for the For Loop when creating temp strings
    Dim tempStr1 As String ' cell value used to concatenate to str1 variable
    Dim str1 As String ' temp string from each cell value for the given row
    Dim aggStr As String ' temp string value used in the while loop
    Dim dataAggCount As Double ' get the last row on the rDataSheet in the while loop
    Dim count As Double: count = 1 ' used to get count of each temp string occurrence
    Dim overallRowCount As Double: overallRowCount = 2 ' this tells me which row to start on my next aggregation
    Dim aggCol As Long ' last column used on the rDataSheet. helps me know where to provide aggregation results (count variable)
    Dim pctdone As Single ' gives the statusBarForm the percentage completion
    Dim reportCount As Double ' used to provide next available row on reportSheet
    Dim sheetarray As Variant ' used to hold the worksheet creation variable. this is done in the while loop
    Dim rDataLastRow As Double ' get last row value when copying filtered data on rDataSheet
    Dim hOverallRowCount As Double ' get the overall row count to know where to paste the data in the sheetarray variable worksheet
    Dim hDataAggCount As Double ' get count of rows on temp string column

    'Variables for worksheets
    Dim rDataSheet As Worksheet: Set rDataSheet = Sheets(1) '!1 Sheet
    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet: Set reportSheet = Sheets(2)
    reportSheet.Name = "Report Summary"

'********** THESE COLLECTION VALUES ARE USER UPDATED ***********

    'Create Collection to hold items that are going to be used in the grouping
    Dim headerColl As New Collection

    headerColl.Add "SIM_c_site_id"
    headerColl.Add "iim_c_FcstName"
    headerColl.Add "iim_c_description"

'*********************************************

    'array to hold all of the column numbers used for each grouping column
    Dim headerArray As Variant
    ReDim headerArray(1 To headerColl.count)

    'variables used to get colum letter
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim colNum As Long
    Dim z As Long

    'get count of fields (columns) with data
    Dim colCount As Long: colCount = rDataSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For z = 1 To headerColl.count
        'find the needed header from header collection and get the column number
        With rDataSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, colCount))
            Set rFind = .Find(What:=headerColl(z), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                'gives me the column number
                colNum = rFind.Column
                'add column number to headerArray
                If z <> headerColl.count + 1 Then
                    headerArray(z) = colNum
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next z
    Set rFind = Nothing

    'insert header from data sheet to report sheet
    reportSheet.Rows(2).Value = rDataSheet.Rows(1).Value

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'***This section will need to be updated once the user wants to add more aggregations (columns)***
'   'Alias the aggregation columns and possible the other columns
'
    'insert column for aggregating
    reportSheet.Cells(2, colCount + 1).Value = "nCount"

    'these variables are used for column numbers of the created columns above
    aggCol = colCount + 1

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'column letter conversion for the aggregation column
    Dim aggReportColLetter As String: aggReportColLetter = Col_Letter(aggCol)

    'column letter conversion for the aggregation column
    Dim lastReportColLetter As String: lastReportColLetter = Col_Letter(aggCol - 1)

    'set the progress label and show the form
    statusBarForm.LabelProgress.Width = 0
    statusBarForm.Show

    'update user on progress of script: this is where the temp strings will be produced and sorted
    With statusBarForm
            .LabelCaption.Caption = "Preparing data aggregation..."
    End With
    DoEvents

    'get count of rows on data sheet
    Dim dataRowCount As Double: dataRowCount = rDataSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'create tempStr column
    rDataSheet.Cells(1, colCount + 1).Value = "tempStr"
    str1 = vbNullString

    'create temp strings
    For y = 2 To dataRowCount
        For x = 1 To UBound(headerArray)
            tempStr1 = Cells(y, headerArray(x))
            str1 = str1 & tempStr1
            tempStr1 = vbNullString
        Next x
        rDataSheet.Cells(y, aggCol) = str1
        str1 = vbNullString
    Next y

    'create filter for sorting temp string column
    rDataSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    'sort temp string column
    Columns("A:" & aggReportColLetter).Sort key1:=Range(aggReportColLetter & "1"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'********** THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS **********
    'SUMMARY:
    ' - filter temp string
    ' - get the count of occurrences of temp string individual
    ' - paste count to 'Report Summary' sheet
    ' - create worksheet and paste aggregated row data results onto each sheet
    ' - do while the the row the temp string is on, is not greater than the overall row count
    Do While overallRowCount < dataRowCount

        'update progress bar percentage
         pctdone = Round((overallRowCount / dataRowCount) * 100, 2)
         With statusBarForm
            .LabelCaption.Caption = "Report Summary is " & pctdone & "%" & " complete."
            .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * 2.7
        End With
        DoEvents

        rDataSheet.Select
        'row item to copy over to the 'Report Summary' sheet
        aggStr = Cells(overallRowCount, aggCol).Value

        'filter '!1' sheet to aggStr variable
        Range("$A$1:$" & aggReportColLetter & "$" & aggCol).AutoFilter Field:=aggCol, Criteria1:=aggStr

        'aggregation count (only counting visible rows)
        count = Application.Subtotal(103, Columns(aggCol)) - 1

        'last used row on the current aggregation
        dataAggCount = rDataSheet.Cells(Rows.count, aggCol).End(xlUp).Row

        'get count of rows on report sheet
        reportCount = reportSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        With reportSheet
        'add row from data sheet to report sheet
            .Rows(reportCount + 1).Value = rDataSheet.Rows(overallRowCount).Value
        'copy aggregated result to 'Report Summary' sheet
            .Cells(reportCount + 1, aggCol).Value = count
        End With

        'next row to use for copying to 'Report Summary' sheet and aggregating
        overallRowCount = dataAggCount + 1

        aggStr = vbNullString

        'create new worksheet that will open up when the hyperlinked number is clicked
        Set sheetarray = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
        sheetarray.Name = "!" & CStr(sheetarray.Index - 1)

''      create hyperlink to sheets created
        reportSheet.Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(reportCount + 1, aggCol), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'" & sheetarray.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=""

        rDataLastRow = rDataSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        hDataAggCount = rDataSheet.Cells(Rows.count, aggCol - 1).End(xlUp).Row

        hOverallRowCount = hDataAggCount - count + 1

        'copy filtered data from rDataSheet and paste into the newly created sheet
        sheetarray.Select
        sheetarray.Range("A1:" & lastReportColLetter & 1).Value = rDataSheet.Range("A1:" & lastReportColLetter & 1).Value
        sheetarray.Range("A2:" & lastReportColLetter & count + 1).Value = rDataSheet.Range("A" & hOverallRowCount & ":" & lastReportColLetter & rDataLastRow).Value
        'format the sheet
        sheetarray.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, aggCol - 1)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        'hide the sheet
        sheetarray.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        rDataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        'set the sheet to nothing, so the same variable can dynamically be used again for the next aggregation row
        Set sheetarray = Nothing
    Loop

'********** Clean up the report and close out the routine **********

    'delete the temp string column
    With rDataSheet
        .Columns(aggCol).Delete
    End With

    'auto fit columns on the Report Summary sheet
    With reportSheet
        .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, aggCol)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    'close out of the status bar
    Unload statusBarForm

    MsgBox "Aggregation results are now availabe!", vbOKOnly, "Aggregation Completion"

    'restore order to the Excel world
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub

'function that converts a number into a column letter
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! I don't have time for a review right now, but I'd be curious what the performance is if you comment-out the progress indicator code? Consider updating progress once every x% of total, rather than at every single iteration.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks! I commented out the progress indicator code, and on the second run, commented out the statusBarForm as a whole and it surprisingly ran on average 2.5 second slower between both runs. For the change in progress update, are you thinking something like ```if overallRowCount / dataRowCount is equal to x% then update the progress indicator``` ?

Comment: As it stands your code won't compile with `Option Explicit` at the top - can you please qualify all variables and edit your question?

Comment: Surprising indeed... did you leave the `DoEvents` in? As for the update, consider `If overallRowCount Mod 100 = 0 Then UpdateProgress` -- regarding the progress indicator itself, you might be interested to read [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/) I wrote a while back (the original code is somewhere on this site!)

Comment: @dwirony Maybe I copy and pasted something incorrectly? It works fine for me. I recopied whole sub, so hopefully that helps.

Comment: Don't have time for a review at the moment. Most of your loops can be accomplished through an array, rather than switching between the Excel model and the VBA model - this will have a big impact on performance.

Comment: @AJD When you have time, I would be interested to know how my loops could be accomplished through an array, rather than switching between the Excel model and the VBA model.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ```DoEvents ``` was not left in I'll have to integrate that snippet of code in the script and see if I have better results. Thanks for the tip on the article btw!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon just a heads-up, I tried  “If overallRowCount Mod 100 = 0 Then UpdateProgress“ but changed it to 1000, and that saved a few seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 6):

In this review, I am only looking at options for addressing the loops. With the number of rows you have described, finding efficiencies in the loops should have a big payoff.

Don't collapse lines of code using ":", it is not necessary, breaks indenting and makes it harder to find some lines.

### Loop 1

```
'get count of fields (columns) with data
Dim colCount As Long
colCount = rDataSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For z = 1 To headerColl.count
    'find the needed header from header collection and get the column number
    With rDataSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, colCount))
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=headerColl(z), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            'gives me the column number
            colNum = rFind.Column
            'add column number to headerArray
            If z <> headerColl.count + 1 Then
                headerArray(z) = colNum
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next z
```

You use the Excel model with `Range`, `.Find`, `.Column`. With your current example, this would only loop 3 times, so is not significant in terms of performance. However, this presents a good training opportunity.

You work with a single range(`rDataSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, colCount))`), but you set that range each time in the loop. If you were using Excel objects, you coud set the `With` statement outside of the loop and save some performance time there.

But you are only working with the values, so this allows us to use Arrays.

```
Dim dataValues as Variant
Dim hCollValue as Variant ' Must be variant to work in a for each loop
dataValues = rDataSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, colCount)).Value
'For each hCollValue in headerColl ' was For z = 1 To headerColl.count
For z = 1 To headerColl.count
    'find the needed header from header collection and get the column number
    For i = LBound(dataValues) to UBound(dataValues)
        If UCase(CStr(dataValues(i,1))) = UCase(CStr(headerColl(z)) Then
            headerArray(z) = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next z
```

Iterating through the entire loop to find the one value (noting that I exit when the first one is found) can be cheaper than calling the equivalent Excel function. You can see now that I am not touching Excel at all during that loop. Because of the use of Variants, I have cast them to strings, and taken the UpperCase to conduct a case-insensitive search.

The array returned by a `Range` of values is always two-dimensional. Because we are taking it from a single column, the array is only one wide, hence why I have used `dataValues(i,1)`

Point to note in your original loop:

```
            'If z <> headerColl.count + 1 Then ' This can never be false, because you are in a loop
            '    headerArray(z) = colNum
            'End If
```

Another thing to consider is the use of a custom class that acts as a data structure. In that way, you could:

```
For Each MyCustomClass in headerColl
    ....
        If dV = MyCustomClass.HeaderTitle Then
            MyCustomClass.ColumnNumber = i
        End If
    ....
Next MyCustomClass
```

Could be a real game changer if you tie lots of data or logic to these items. I suggest a `Class` and not a `Type` because you cannot iterate over a `Type` collection in VBA and there are some other wrinkles.

### Loop 2

```
'create temp strings
For y = 2 To dataRowCount
    For x = 1 To UBound(headerArray)
        tempStr1 = Cells(y, headerArray(x))
        str1 = str1 & tempStr1
        tempStr1 = vbNullString
    Next x
    rDataSheet.Cells(y, aggCol) = str1
    str1 = vbNullString
Next y
```

This is where you are going to get the real performance hit. I am also finding it difficult to unpack the loop and what you are trying to achieve. If I am interpreting this right, you are creating a temporary string out of the values across the row (selected columns only), and putting this string into another column on the same row. Except in a different sheet.

Note: Always use qualified ranges, as you can't really tell which is the active sheet once the code is running.

```
Dim sourceStrings as Variant ` this will be a multi-dimensional array
Dim targetArray(dataRowCount - 2 + 1, 1) as String

Dim unionRange as Range
Dim r as Long, r2 as Long
With [ThisSheet] ' whatever you have set this sheet too - qualify all ranges.
    For r = LBound(headerArray) to UBound(headerArray)
        If unionRange is Nothing Then
            set unionRange = .Range(.Cells(2, headerArray(r)),.Cells(dataRowCount, headerArray(r)) )
        Else
            set unionRange = Union(unionRange, .Range(.Cells(2, headerArray(r)),.Cells(dataRowCount, headerArray(r))))
        End If
    Next r
End With 
sourceStrings = unionRange.Value

For r = LBound(sourceStrings,1) to UBound(sourceStrings,1) ' loop through the first dimension - but "1" is optional default and not really needed here.
    targetArray(r) = vbNullString '""
    For r2 = LBound(sourceStrings,2) to UBound(sourceStrings,2) ' loop through the second dimension
        targetArray(r) = targetArray(r) & sourceStrings(r, r2)
    Next r2
Next r  
With rDataSheet
    .Range(.Cells(2,aggCol),.Cells(dataRowCount,aggCol)).Value = targetArray
End With
```

The first `r` loop seems a bit complicated, but it is short (3 iterations in your example) and it now sets up the quicker array.
DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this. Possible may require some tweaking if Excel does funky things with values from a multi-area range.

Instead of switching in and out of Excel (headers * rowcount + rowcount) times, you would only do it (headers + insert values) times - which in this case is about 4 times.

### Loop 3

Sometimes, there is not much that can be done. I have had a quick look, but I don't think using Arrays here is going to help much because of the diverse amount of data and Excel object items (not just `.Value`) that are used. Avoid using `.Select`.

Comment: To answer your question on Loop 2: what I am doing is grabbing all cell values for the first row, concatenating them into a temp string, pasting them into the same row, but in a new column (taking the last column index +1 to know where to input the "temp string" column) and then repeating for each row. This is all done on the same sheet.With this amount of rows, it is currently taking ~3.5 seconds to complete. I am using a column to store the temp strings, so I can then sort them to get my duplicates in chunks. This helps not having to take the each temp string and check that against every row

Comment: To answer your question on Loop 3: I was initially trying to avoid using ```.Select```, but I ran into errors. Mainly when trying to create the hyperlink ```ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(reportCount + 1, aggCol), Address:="", SubAddress:= "'" & sheetarray.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=""``` and in this line of code when using the "sheetarray" sheet ```sheetarray.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, aggCol - 1)).EntireColumn.AutoFit``` When I used the ```sheetname.Select``` first, the errors disappeared.

Comment: To respond to your Loop 1: The code I was using took milliseconds to complete, so I wasn't too concerned with this section of the code. I did, though, use the block of code you provided, as it looks a lot cleaner than what I was using.

Answer (score 4):

With this review, I hope to offer an alternative approach to your stated problem by using a SQL query.

Instead of copying your data into subdivided sheets, I think a better fit to your stated problem would be simply query or filter the data you want to find, when you need it. Leave your raw data as is, and just pull it up on demand when needed. I chose to use `ADODB` with a SQL statement, but you could achieve something very similar with `AutoFilter` or `Advanced Filter` too.

***How is this better? (IMO)***

- By copying your unique groups into new sheets, you are effectively doubling your raw data size. With this approach, your raw data remains untouched, you just summarize it.
- You don't need to create 300+ sheets, you'd only ever need 2 sheets (given the stated problem). A summary sheet and a raw data sheet. A lot easier to debug is something goes awry.
- No column concatenation is needed with this approach. Instead of making a composite key (of sorts) with 4 columns of joined data, simply filter (or query) the columns with the values you need for each column. BTW, concatenating all columns again, doubles the size of your data...again.

I've mocked up a spreadsheet with 150,000 rows of data in Worksheet called `Raw Data`. This sheet has 4 columns of randomly generated single characters to mock up what you described.

[image: Raw Data]

You'll also need a sheet named `Summary`, this is where the data is output to.

The way this work is it will find all matching rows that match the parameters you supply for Column 1 through 4. Each Column value needs to match what you provided to get returned.

The code below has querying approach built out. I didn't create a form/UI to pass in values, however that should be fairly easy to do now, just update the `SearchParameters` type, you can do this in the `CreateView` sub. The performance is pretty good, queries are taking less than 2 seconds to finish on my machine.

Let me know if there are any questions, happy to help.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Private Const adCmdText As Long = 1
Private Const adVarWChar As Long = 202
Private Const adParamInput As Long = 1

Public Type SearchParameters
    Column1Value As String
    Column2Value As String
    Column3Value As String
    Column4Value As String
End Type

Private Function GetExcelConnection() As Object
    Set GetExcelConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    GetExcelConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                                          ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"
    GetExcelConnection.Open
End Function

Private Sub DisplayFilteredRawData(SQLParameters As SearchParameters)
    Const SQL               As String = "SELECT [Column 1],[Column 2],[Column 3],[Column 4] " & _
                                        "FROM [Raw Data$] " & _
                                        "WHERE [Column 1] = ? and [Column 2] = ? and [Column 3] = ? and [Column 4] = ?"
    Static dbConnection      As Object
    Static OutputSheet       As Excel.Worksheet
    Static OutputRange       As Excel.Range
    Static RecordCount       As Excel.Range
    Dim FilteredRS           As Object
    Const MaxCellLength      As Long = 32767
    Const NumberOfHeaderRows As Long = 4

    If OutputSheet Is Nothing Then Set OutputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    If OutputRange Is Nothing Then Set OutputRange = OutputSheet.Range("A5:F100000") 'Where data is output
    If RecordCount Is Nothing Then Set RecordCount = OutputSheet.Range("F4") 'Where the record count goes
    If dbConnection Is Nothing Then Set dbConnection = GetExcelConnection

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
       .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
       .CommandType = adCmdText
       .CommandText = SQL
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Value1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, MaxCellLength, SQLParameters.Column1Value)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Value2", adVarWChar, adParamInput, MaxCellLength, SQLParameters.Column2Value)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Value3", adVarWChar, adParamInput, MaxCellLength, SQLParameters.Column3Value)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Value4", adVarWChar, adParamInput, MaxCellLength, SQLParameters.Column4Value)
       Set FilteredRS = .Execute
    End With

    OutputRange.Clear
    If Not FilteredRS Is Nothing Then
        OutputSheet.Range(OutputRange.Cells(1, 1).Address).CopyFromRecordset FilteredRS
    End If
    RecordCount.Value2 = OutputSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row - NumberOfHeaderRows
End Sub

Public Sub CreateView()
    Dim myTimer As Double: myTimer = Timer
    Dim mySearchParameters As SearchParameters

    With mySearchParameters
        .Column1Value = "l"
        .Column2Value = "o"
        .Column3Value = "l"
        .Column4Value = "z"
    End With

    DisplayFilteredRawData mySearchParameters
    Debug.Print Timer - myTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: @AJD. I updated the answer slightly. I mention in my post there isn't a UI built out, but how to update the parameters for the query.

Comment: Pt.1 -This a thoughtful approach, but I don't think that this fits with what I am needing to do. The amount of rows on the sheet and the kind of data that will be provided on the "DataSheet" will vary each time the user pulls this data from a website and exports it to this Excel sheet, which houses the VBA script. With that being said, my goal when the user exports and opens the Excel doc is to get a summary sheet of all duplicate values based off of the grouping (set by the admin in the VBA code - Collection data), their count and a hyperlink to all the data when clicking the count hyperlink.

Comment: Pt. 2 - The hyperlink would then open up their respective sheet with all of the data that pertains to the grouping used. I may have 15 columns in the raw data, but only want to group by 4 columns. The hyperlink count, let's say is 10, would give me the 10 rows of data that pertain to my grouping.

Comment: Gotcha, if you want to return everything (e.g. all columns). You can change this part `SELECT [Column 1],[Column 2],[Column 3],[Column 4]` to `SELECT *`. This approach should work regardless of how many rows are returned.

Answer (score 4):

I like the project but ...

### Separation of Concerns

It is best to keep your procedure under 40 lines.  Generally speaking, it is best to identify each task that is to be performed, divide the tasks up and have subprocedures that process one or two of them at a time.  The main method would be responsible for passing data between the methods as parameters.  It is much easier to debug and modify a small block of code then it is to run complex subroutine before you can test a code block.

### Qualify References

You should avoid selecting and activating objects whenever possible.  Using fully qualified ranges will make the code more efficient and less fragile.

This line fails if `rDataSheet` is not the ActiveSheet because of the cells within the range not being qualified to `rDataSheet`.  They are referencing the cells on the ActiveSheet.

> ```
> With rDataSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, colCount))
> ```

Here is how to properly reference ranges:

> ```
> With rDataSheet
>     .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, colCount))
> ```

### Generating Unique Keys

It is important to use a delimiter when creating a key.

Generating keys for the table below without using a delimiter only yields two unique keys, even though, all rows are unique.

+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
| 12       | 34       |
+----------+----------+
| 123      | 4        |
+----------+----------+
| 1234     |          |
+----------+----------+
| ABC      | DF       |
+----------+----------+

### User Experience (UX)

- Hyperlinking to a hidden sheet. I'm guessing you'll fix this using the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event
- 330 hidden WorkSheets?  You probably just delete them between runs but wouldn't it be easier to create a new Workbook for the report?

### Naming Convention

- `headerColl`: This is obviously the Column Headers. Oh, my mistake, it is the columns used to generate unique keys.  But doesn't "concatenate each cell in the row into a temp string variable" suggest that each cell in the row is part of the unique key?  This explains why there is a worksheet for each key.  Otherwise, all the rows per each key worksheet would be identical.  Anyway, I would use `keyColumns`.
- rDataLastRow: DataLastRow
- rDataSheet: DataSheet, wsData
- tempStr1: There is value in being able to watch tempStr1 in the Locals Window or add a watch. But in my opinion, it is just clutter.  Helper variables should be used to make the code more readable.  This looks easier to read to me:

  ```
  For x = 1 To UBound(headerArray)
      str1 = str1 & Cells(y, headerArray(x))
  Next x
  ```

### Can it be done faster?

Hell yeah.
Altough, not 100% to specs, this code is over 8 times faster.

```
Option Explicit
Private Const Delimiter As String = "|"

Sub Main()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim groups As New Scripting.Dictionary, subDic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set groups = getRowsGroupedByDuplicateKeyColumns(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1), 1, 2, 3, 4)

    Dim wbReport As Workbook
    Set wbReport = CreateReport(groups)

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In groups
        Set subDic = groups(key)
        AddDuplicatesWorksheet wbReport, subDic
    Next
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 2)
End Sub

Private Function CreateReport(ByRef groups As Scripting.Dictionary) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Dim subDic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant, results As Variant

    For Each key In groups
        Set subDic = groups(key)
        '.......
    Next

    Set CreateReport = wb
End Function

Private Sub AddDuplicatesWorksheet(wbReport As Workbook, subDic As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim key As Variant, results() As Variant, rowData() As Variant

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For Each key In subDic
        rowData = subDic(key)
        If r = 0 Then ReDim results(1 To subDic.count, 1 To UBound(rowData) + 1)

        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = key
        For c = 1 To UBound(rowData)
            results(r, c + 1) = rowData(c)
        Next
    Next

    With wbReport.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
    End With

End Sub

Private Function getRowsGroupedByDuplicateKeyColumns(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ParamArray KeyColumns() As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim data() As Variant
    With ws
        data = .Range(.Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))).Value
    End With

    Dim key As Variant, keyData() As Variant, rowData() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, keyIndex As LongPtr
    ReDim keyData(0 To UBound(KeyColumns))
    ReDim rowData(1 To UBound(data, 2))

    For r = 2 To UBound(data)
        For c = 0 To UBound(KeyColumns)
            keyIndex = KeyColumns(c)
            keyData(c) = data(r, keyIndex)
        Next
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            rowData(c) = data(r, c)
        Next
        key = Join(keyData, Delimiter)
        If Not dic.Exists(key) Then dic.Add key, New Scripting.Dictionary
        dic(key).Add r, rowData
    Next
    Set getRowsGroupedByDuplicateKeyColumns = dic
End Function
```